# Export Compliance Information. Does your app use encryption? in TestFlight

Tags: ios, https, app-store-connect, testflight

[image]

Getting the above message after the successfully uploaded the app in TestFlight.

I am not using app any encryption but making a call to the HTTPS in the app. I'm not getting what exactly needs to be done.

How to Know if any third party plugin is using encryption ?